# Angular 2 example app returns error "Cannot read property 'X' of null"

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2 and I am trying run sample applications from GitHub. I downloaded [the sample application](https://github.com/AngularShowcase/angular2-sample-app).

When I am trying to serve the application, it's giving me the following error as shown below in the screen shot:

[image]

How can I resolve the error?

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "material2-srcs",
  "description": "Material Design components for Angular",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/material2",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/angular/material2/issues",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/material2.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngc -p angular.tsconfig.json",
    "build": "gulp :publish:build-releases",
    "demo-app": "gulp serve:devapp",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "tslint": "gulp lint",
    "stylelint": "gulp lint",
    "e2e": "gulp e2e",
    "deploy": "gulp deploy:devapp",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "docs": "gulp docs",
    "api": "gulp api-docs"
  },
  "version": "5.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 5.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.43",
    "tsickle": "^0.24.x",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/bazel": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^5.0.1",
    "@bazel/ibazel": "^0.1.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.31",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/glob": "^5.0.33",
    "@types/gulp": "3.8.32",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/merge2": "^0.3.30",
    "@types/minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.21",
    "@types/run-sequence": "^0.0.29",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.6",
    "axe-core": "^2.3.1",
    "axe-webdriverjs": "^1.1.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "dgeni": "^0.4.9",
    "dgeni-packages": "^0.22.0",
    "firebase": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.11.0",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "google-closure-compiler": "20170409.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-conventional-changelog": "^1.1.3",
    "gulp-dom": "^0.9.17",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-highlight-files": "^0.0.5",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-markdown": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.11.0",
    "http-rewrite-middleware": "^0.1.6",
    "image-diff": "^1.6.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-browserstack-launcher": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-sauce-launcher": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "madge": "^2.2.0",
    "magic-string": "^0.22.4",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "^5.2.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "resolve-bin": "^0.4.0",
    "rollup": "^0.41.6",
    "rollup-plugin-alias": "^1.3.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "scss-bundle": "^2.0.1-beta.7",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.6.0",
    "sorcery": "^0.10.0",
    "stylelint": "^7.12.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^2.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "tsutils": "^2.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.2",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.14",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: seems you dont have compatible cli and javascript.....have you installed specified cli and typescript??????

Comment: try running the typescript command once. npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 < 2.5.0'

Comment: Can you please provide the error in text instead of as a screenshot?

Comment: yes ,, the error is as below
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first run `npm install` 

 If `npm install` not working then try this.

Please add following file at root folder File Name-.angular-cli.json

```
 {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "xyz"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "assets/css/styles.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
                "assets/js/project.js"      

            ],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the above solution but i m getting this error "
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Comment: and after running     >npm ls @angular/compiler-cli   i m getting this below errro ....| `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.6.2 invalid

npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6, required by @angular/bazel@5.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6, required by @angular/compiler-cli@5.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@2.4.2, required by tsickle@0.24.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6, required by tsickle@0.25.5

Comment: add above file in root directory ..?

Comment: Can you provide your package.json? if package.json present in your project folder then `npm install`

Comment: i edited my post and added package.json file..please check

Comment: ok remove node module and remove this sign in `~ & ^ ` in package.json and npm install after that `ng serve`

Comment: and it's version problem

Comment: install @angular/cli based on your project because you get this error `The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed` and will try

Answer (score 0):

have u done **npm install** first?

maybe if u have installed all the necessary component i think u have to run with: **npm run serve.dev** or **npm run test**

Comment: yes i have installed node js .and i tried running simple login application also . it ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

try installing the latest npm or just run this command in your project directory this command will automatically install dependent modules in your node modules folder. if not try manually installation command for coming error like installing angular-cli and typescript. commands are easily available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular)

sudo npm install.

after this, you can run your project by npm serve

Comment: but when i am running sudo npm install its giving me this error 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: i am really sorry in windows sudo command wont work. try manually adding one by one module. i have doubt if you are executing npm install command from your project folder only.

Comment: should i install all these mentioned below

Comment: npm install --save @angular/common

npm install --save @angular/compiler @angular/core @angular/forms @angular/http @angular/paltform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @angular/router

npm install --save core-js rxjs zone.js

npm install --save systemjs

npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node

Comment: yes, definitely it will also help you to update your old modules.

Comment: if not try this out 

npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save

Comment: i tried doing the above mentioned step but then i am getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161290/discussion-between-hrishikesh-kale-and-prince-varghese).

Comment: it is not your npm issue for any module issue but it is angular-cli file issue. which is not there in your project structure. please find the solution here 

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736

you can copy your old cli file into the new one.

Comment: i went through the link but no solution is working for me